# How to configure public IP behind a modem/router (Actiontec GT724R)

Tags: router, nat, modem, ipcop

I want to figureout how to use a public IP address (ISP provided) behind the modem/router.

I'm replacing an aging modem with a NEW one, which is an actiontec GT724R modem.  Its manual is [Here](http://www.actiontec.com/products/manuals/GT724R_NCS_User_Manual-v1.1_3.0.4.0.x_s.pdf)

This is how I want the setup to look like

```
                        IP Cop Server                            GT724R Modem
                          |        |                              |       | 
    GREEN (internal)      |        |RED (outside network)         |       | WAN IP
     ---------------------|        |------------------------------|       |------------
    10.0.0.1                       66.92.41.254                             66.92.41.44
```

There's an IPCop Server sitting right behind the GT724R with 2 Nics.
10.0.0.1 is internal network (GREEN) and  66.92.41.254 (RED) will be the public one.

66.92.41.254 and 66.92.41.44 are ISP provided Static IPs.

The IP COP svr is already configured this way and has a lot of setup work done already using 66.92.41.254, so hence I want to continue 
to use the public address.

The old modem was in bridged mode and the new one (GT724R) is also configured to run in a similar style, which is "RFC 1483 via Static IP"
Encapsulation is "RFC 1483 bridged"

Thanks
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the new modem is indeed running in bridge mode as well, then the second/new IP should not be tied to the modem at all. It would be on the same plane as your IP Cop server/firewall. In fact, you may even be able to configure IP Cop to manage the second IP as well.

Comment: Appreciate the response, but I'm not clear about what you mean.  So dont tie any IP address with the modem?

Comment: If the modem is truly in bridge mode, it will not utilize the routable Internet IP. It may have a management IP, but it may not "reveal" that unless it is in maintenance mode (e.g. unable to connect to the ISP network). Is this a DSL or cable modem?

Comment: Awesome that helped a lot.  I changed the mode to a "RFC 1483 transparent Bridging" mode, which doesnt need any static ip.  The earlier mode I was using needed a static IP.  Now the modem runs as truely bridged i guess and everything is working the way I wanted it.  Its funny how I completely overlooked it earlier.  This is a DSL modem btw.  thanks for your help.  But now I've lost access to the modem....need to figureout how to run it in maintenance mode....but thats a different question i guess

Comment: You don't really need access to the modem, but you can try to disconnect the ISP/WAN end and then try grabbing a DHCP lease from its LAN end - you may need to power cycle the unit while in such an arrangement.